# Product images are not showing in magneto admin panel after updating security patch

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have get update for security patch and then after in admin panel product images are not display same for image upload button. Have file permission 755 for media folder. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Please try Change the permissions of the ‘media’ folder in your root to 755 or 777 recursively for the sub-folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Speedster extension Fooman, try disabling that. Unmerge js files from admin.

Comment: No. We don't have this type of extension